# Hibernate using random unspecified column names in queries

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I'm having trouble with the hibernate mappings of two tables in my DB schema. One is called `BINARY_DATA_CONTENTS` and the other is `BINARY_DATA`. `BINARY_DATA` just has a name field, and a pointer to `BINARY_DATA_CONTENTS`. This is what the schemas look like:

BINARY_DATA_CONTENTS:

```
CREATE TABLE `BINARY_DATA_CONTENTS` (
  `BINARY_DATA_CONTENTS_ID` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `BINARY_DATA` longblob, -- stores the data
  PRIMARY KEY (`BINARY_DATA_CONTENTS_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

BINARY_DATA:

```
CREATE TABLE `BINARY_DATA` (
  `BINARY_DATA_ID` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `BINARY_DATA_NAME` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL, -- just a filename
  `BINARY_DATA_CONTENTS_ID` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL, -- points to BINARY_DATA_CONTENTS
  PRIMARY KEY (`BINARY_DATA_ID`),
  KEY `BINARY_DATA_CONTENTS_FK` (`BINARY_DATA_CONTENTS_ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `BINARY_DATA_CONTENTS_FK` FOREIGN KEY (`BINARY_DATA_CONTENTS_ID`) REFERENCES `BINARY_DATA_CONTENTS` (`BINARY_DATA_CONTENTS_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

I have Java classes for each of these tables.

BinaryDataContents:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="BINARY_DATA_CONTENTS")
@Proxy(lazy=true)
@Inheritance(strategy= InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class BinaryDataContents implements Serializable, Persistable<BinaryDataContents>, Cloneable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = /** blah */;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator="uuid") @GenericGenerator(name="uuid", strategy="uuid")
    @Column(name="BINARY_DATA_CONTENTS_ID")
    private String id;

    @Column(name="BINARY_DATA", length=32*1024*1024, columnDefinition="longblob") @Lob
    private byte[] contents;

    /**
     * Hibernate constructor
     */
    public BinaryDataContents() { }

    public BinaryDataContents(byte[] contents) {
        this.contents = ArrayUtils.clone(contents);
    }

    public byte[] getContents() {
        return contents;
    }
    // etc...
```

BinaryData:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="BINARY_DATA")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class BinaryData implements Serializable, Persistable<BinaryData>, Cloneable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2154854247822039938L;

    @Id @Column @GeneratedValue(generator="uuid") @GenericGenerator(name="uuid", strategy="uuid")
    private String id;

    @Column
    private String binaryDataName;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="BINARY_DATA_CONTENTS_ID", nullable=true) @ForeignKey(name="BINARY_DATA_CONTENTS_FK")
    private Collection<BinaryDataContents> binaryDataContents;

    @Transient
    private String cacheId;

    /**
     * Hibernate constructor
     */
    public BinaryData() { this.binaryDataContents = Sets.newHashSet(new BinaryDataContents()); }

    /**
     * Create a new instance of BinaryData.
     *
     * @param binaryDataData <code>byte []</code> of the file to store.
     * @param binaryDataName Name of attachment
     */
    public BinaryData(byte[] binaryDataData, String binaryDataName) {
        this.binaryDataContents = Sets.newHashSet(new BinaryDataContents(ArrayUtils.clone(binaryDataData)));
        this.binaryDataName = binaryDataName;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the BinaryData byte stream.
     *
     * @return binaryDataContents byte stream
     */
    public byte[] getData() {
        return binaryDataContents.iterator().next().getContents();
    }

    /**
     * Returns the BinaryData name.
     *
     * @return BinaryData name
     */
    public String getBinaryDataName() {
        return binaryDataName;
    }
    // etc...
```

I'd like to have `BinaryDataContents` be lazy loaded, only when it's needed (via `getData` in `BinaryData`). I'm not sure that I have all of my annotations set up correctly, since I get an error when trying to save a new `BinaryData` object:

`PersistenceException: Failed to commit`
`Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Could not execute JDBC batch update`
`Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Unknown column 'AUTHORISATION_REQUEST_ID' in 'field list'`

This is odd, because there is no column or field anywhere called `AUTHORISATION_REQUEST_ID` in those tables or classes. It appears that hibernate has gone haywire, and is throwing strange column names into the SQL:

`insert into BINARY_DATA (BINARY_DATA_NAME, AUTHORISATION_REQUEST_ID) values (?, ?)`

Any ideas about what could be causing this? Thank you.

**UPDATE 1**

If I use the `@OneToOne` annotation, the error changes slightly. The `BINARY_DATA_CONTENTS` insert appears to generate the right SQL:

`insert into BINARY_DATA_CONTENTS (BINARY_DATA, BINARY_DATA_CONTENTS_ID) values (?, ?)`

However, the `BINARY_DATA` insert still has a random column name in it:

`insert into BINARY_DATA (BINARY_DATA_CONTENTS_ID, BINARY_DATA_NAME, AUTHORISATION_REQUEST_ID) values (?, ?, ?)`

**UPDATE 2**

The strage `AUTHORISATION_REQUEST_ID` column that appears to come from nowhere changes based on the order that I register all of my hibernate annotated classes with my application (sometimes it's `DATABASE_UPGRADE_ID`). The application retains a list of these classes and passes them to some sort of insane PersistenceConfiguration, which does all sorts of weird stuff with it. It's probably caused by that...

Answer (score 0):

Don't know where this AUTHORIZATION_REQUEST_ID comes from. Probably from soething you don't show us. But your mapping is clearly wrong. The binary data has a foreign key to the binary data contents.

So this means that a binary data may only have one binary data contents. So, if several binary data may share the same contents, you should have a ManyToOne. Else, you should have a OneToOne. A OneToMany is of course not what you want, and the fact that you use a Set and are only interested in its first element is a strong indication that it's wrong. Here's how it should be:

```
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "BINARY_DATA_CONTENTS_ID", nullable=true) 
@ForeignKey(name = "BINARY_DATA_CONTENTS_FK")
private BinaryDataContents binaryDataContents;
```

Comment: There's nothing below with an `AUTHORISATION_REQUEST_ID`... it's something hibernate is pulling out of thin air. I originally had a `@OneToOne`, but was getting a similar error, so I tried the `@OneToMany` hack with a collection. Check my edited question to see the error that I was getting with `@OneToOne`. `BinaryData` can only refer to one `BinaryDataContents`, so the `@oneToOne` should be fine.

Comment: You probably have another entity with a OneToMany association to BinaryData with a JoinColumn called AUTHORIZATION_REQUEST_ID.

Comment: It actually appears that this giant enterprise-y application is doing some horrible stuff behind the scenes (see update 2 above). There's no `AUTHORISATION_REQUEST_ID` in any other entity that references BinaryData.